# Side bar and Main content will not show side by side in CSS and HTML:

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a website that focuses on helping individuals with university admissions. I am about to apply to universities and I felt like my concerns and troubles are the same as others. My problem here is that the side bar and the main "content" won't appear side by side and I have tried everything within my power to absolve the problem. Could anyone help me :)
This is the html code

```
<div class= "sidenav">
<a href = "">Latest Blog Posts</a>
    <a href = " ">Why You are more successful than you think</a>

</div>
<div class= "main">
    <div class= "content">
<div class="card">
<h1 style="font-size: 50px;">Submit!</h1>
<p style="font-size: 20px">Thank you for considering working with 
DaddyChill and submitting!<br>Submitting your notes will mean that 
you've helped someone with their highschool test!<br> If you want to 
submit just click the link below!<br>
</div> 
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
.content{
position: relative;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
padding:20px;
}
.card{
background-color: white;


}

.sidenav{
height: 100%;
width: 160px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 20px;
}
.sidenav a{
padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: white;
display: block;
}
.sidenav a:hover{
color: yellow;
}
.main{
margin-left: 160px;
font-size: 28px;
        padding: 1px 10px;

}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px){
.sidenav {padding-top:15px;}
.sidenav a { font-size: 18px}
}
```

Comment: You're much better off using a layout method such as grid or flexbox if you want to achieve this. I'd recommend using grid for this one. Just put everything in a grid-container, with `display grid` and `grid-template-columns: 160px calc(100% - 160px)`

Comment: Just in `.sidenav` remove `position:relative` and add `float: left`.

Comment: @sven `grid-template-columns: 160px auto;` would have been much easier. Auto occupies the remainign space. However if you just have a single row, then flexbox would be the better solution and using flex-grow

Comment: Thank you all very much for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

Added grid support to your example. You'll need to tweak your paddings and margins but your layout should work.

```css
    .container {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      grid-gap: 36px;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
      align-items: flex-start;
      flex-direction: column;

    }

    .content {
      position: relative;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .card {
      background-color: white;


    }

    .sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
      padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: white;
      display: block;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: yellow;
    }

    .main {
      font-size: 28px;
      padding: 1px 10px;


    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
      }

      .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="sidenav">
      <a href="">Latest Blog Posts</a>
      <a href=" ">Why You are more successful than you think</a>

    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="card">
          <h1 style="font-size: 50px;">Submit!</h1>
          <p style="font-size: 20px">Thank you for considering working with
            DaddyChill and submitting!<br>Submitting your notes will mean that
            you've helped someone with their highschool test!<br> If you want to
            submit just click the link below!<br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, I really appreciate  and thank you very much for the code!